# HTML CSS: Carousel Add Numbers inside Bubbles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I add numbers to the carousel example below? Bubbles should have numbers in them. Right now they are empty bubbles in the code example from w3 school below.

[image]

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated snippet:

```css
.carousel-indicators li {
  text-indent: 0!important;
  width: 25px!important;
  height: 25px!important;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 50px!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f.png/fff" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f.png/fff" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f.png/fff" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ! do you know how to increase size of circles by any chance also?

Comment: Just increase width and height for indicator